# How to store in Storage using Overhead Hanger in Anylogic?

Tags: anylogic

I am working on a model, where I need to store Containers (Agents) in a yard using Overhead Crane. The containers are supposed to stacked upon another container.

I am using a Storage (Material Handling Library) and made it transparent, and use the overhead the crane to move the container to a certain point, after that the containers are independently stored in the Storage.

This makes the animation to look a bit odd, I am looking for a way where the overhead crane can store the container stacked upon each other in some other way so that the animation looks realistic.

[image]

Comment: What exactly do you need? Always ensure your questions are closed, avoid open-ended "I am looking for some other way" questions :)

Comment: I need Overhead Cranes, to store in the Storage.

Comment: I see an overhead crane in the image... I am confused :)

Comment: Now, the overhead cranes transport the crane to a point 1, and then the containers are independently move to the storage.